# How to compare Associated enums that has no associated value in it

Tags: swift, enums

Can I compare associated enum case that has no associated value. Let check the below  snippet of code

```
//Declare associated enum  
enum Example
{
    case test(x:Int)
    case test1(x:String)
}

//Creating enum with associated value
let testWithAssociatedValue = Example.test(x:0)
if case .test = testWithAssociatedValue { //WorksFine
}

//Now having enum with no associated value
let testWithNoAssociatedValue = Example.test

Now Why comparing enum that has no associated value like below,gives me compile error?.
if case .test = testWithNoAssociatedValue {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Example.test` is not an enum case. Try either putting your code in a playground, or checking `type(of: Example.test)`. It will give you `(Int) -> Example`. That is, under the hood, `Example.test` behaves like a function that requires an `Int` and gives you back an `Example` object. That's why `Example.test(x: 10)` gives you that enum case.

The notion of "having an associated enum that has no associated value" doesn't make sense. It sounds like you want to make the associated type *optional*, so you can say `Example.test(x: nil)`.